# Django - Create table from list of list

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am not very good with table in html, so this question might be very simple to answer.

I pass the list of list `{{ attributes }}` to the template and I want to create a table with 2 rows and many columns.

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<div id="table">
<table border=0>
{% for attr in attributes %}
    <td>
       <th>{{ attr.0 }}</th>
        {{ attr.1 }}
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
```

I want the `{{ attr.0 }}` to be the header and displayed on a single row and the `{{ attr.1 }}` displayed on the second row.

Comment: You have a <th> within <td> which is not right. What does {{attributes}} contain?

Comment: {{attributes}} is a list of list [['header','value'], ... ]]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a recursive table in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442368/how-to-create-a-recursive-table-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
<div id="table">
<table border=0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    {% for attr_head in attributes.keys %}
       <th>{{ attr_head }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    {% for attr in attributes.values %}
        <td>{{ attr }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Just loop through the dict's keys and rendering them as `th` elements in the table header and then loop through the values, rendering them inside the `tbody`. `th` and `td` are columns in the table and `tr` are rows.

Also, you should read up on [html tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp), they aren't that hard

Comment: I was thinking about using two loops like your proposal, but I wonder if its possible to do the same within a single loop?

Comment: Not really in this case. If you were to render many rows and 2 columns, it would be very simple though

Comment: Ok thank you. I will accept yours, because you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop twice, once for headers once for content?

```
<div id="table">
    <table border=0>
        <tr>
            {% for attr in attributes %}  
            <th>{{ attr.0 }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        <tr>
            {% for attr in attributes %}
                <td>{{ attr.1 }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```